# wp 8.1 start music from a background task

Tags: c#, media-player, accelerometer, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app (non-silverlight).
What I'm able to do at the moment:

1-I'm able to activate a background task from the UI that reads the accelerometer readings even when the screen is locked or the app is closed  using

```
DeviceUseTrigger
```

and

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder
```

2-I'm able to activate a background task from the UI that plays an audio file even when the screen is locked or the app is closed using the

```
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current
```

Now what I need to do is to play an alarm from the first task even when there is no UI. In other words the first task should be able to Run the second one. Using the BackgroundMediaPlayer does not work anywhere beside the UI thread...

Any help or idea would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer` ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.aspx)) class by any chance?  I'm not sure if that works in a background task but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Would have been too easy